# validate input field on provided pattern

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an input field in the `bootstrap` form which is validate as the user changes the `model`. I have a feedback `help-block` with the input field which is to be validated. However, the provided pattern validation is not working. Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group" show-errors='{showSuccess: true}'>
                            <label>ID</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="programID" ng-model="programID"  pattern="^[A-Z]{2}$"
                                   required>

                            <p class="help-block" ng-style="{'display':conf.display}"
                               ng-if="programID.$error.required">program ID is required</p>
                            <p class="help-block" ng-style="{'display':conf.display}"
                               ng-if="programID.$error.pattern">program ID is invalid</p>
                        </div>
```

The pattern needs to validate only `uppercase` letters, strictly 2 in length.. The field is validated against `empty`, but not for the provided pattern..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
pattern="^[A-Z]{2}$"
```

with

```
ng-pattern="/^[A-Z]{2}$/"
```

From [documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/api/ng/directive/input)

> If the expression evaluates to a RegExp object, then this is used directly. If the expression evaluates to a string, then it will be converted to a RegExp after wrapping it in ^ and $ characters. For instance, "abc" will be converted to new RegExp('^abc$')

Comment: I get this error: `Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 6 of the expression [[A-Z]{2}] starting at [{2}].`

Comment: Hm, which version of angular do you use? Try with a RegEx litteral (see edit)